# How to sum an aggregation on mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

i have this aggregation and i need to show a new object with sum of the GroupScore in the same takeoff of every competition inside the typeGroup, it can be a new aggretation or inside the same.
(EventId, HorseID and CompetitorID makes the ID of the TakeOff to be the same on all competitions)
Thanks for helping me!

```
 const takeOffs = await TakeOff.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: Event.collection.name,
        localField: "event",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "event",
      },
    },
    {
      $unwind: {
        path: "$event",
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
      },
    },
    {
      $match: {
        "event.typeGroup": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id),
        GroupPosition: {
          $exists: true,
          $ne: null,
        },
        GroupScore: {
          $exists: true,
          $ne: null,
        },
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: Competition.collection.name,
        localField: "competition",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "competition",
      },
    },
    {
      $unwind: {
        path: "$competition",
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: Competitor.collection.name,
        localField: "competitor",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "competitor",
      },
    },
    {
      $unwind: {
        path: "$competitor",
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: Horse.collection.name,
        localField: "horse",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "horse",
      },
    },
    {
      $unwind: {
        path: "$horse",
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: Category.collection.name,
        localField: "competition.category",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "category",
      },
    },
    {
      $unwind: {
        path: "$category",
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
      },
    },
    {
      $sort: {
        "category.name": 1,
        GroupPosition: 1,
      },
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: {
          competitionId: "$category.name",
          eventId: "$event._id",
        },
        eventName: { $first: "$event.name" },
        stage: { $first: "$event.stage" },
        takeoffs: {
          $push: {
            _id: "$_id",
            competitorName: "$competitor.name",
            horseName: "$horse.name",
            score: "$score",
            GroupScore: "$GroupScore",
            GroupPosition: "$GroupPosition",
          },
        },
      },
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: "$_id.eventId",
        eventName: { $first: "$eventName" },
        stage: { $first: "$stage" },

        competitions: {
          $push: {
            competition: "$_id.competitionId",
            takeoffs: "$takeoffs",
          },
        },
      },
    },

    {
      $group: {
        _id: "$_id.competitionId",

        events: {
          $push: {
            _id: "$_id.event",
            eventName: "$eventName",
            stage: "$stage",
            competitions: "$competitions",
          },
        },
      },
    },
  ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay i got it, here is the awnser:

```
const takeOffs = await TakeOff.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: Event.collection.name,
        localField: "event",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "event",
      },
    },
    {
      $unwind: {
        path: "$event",
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: Competition.collection.name,
        localField: "competition",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "competition",
      },
    },
    {
      $unwind: {
        path: "$competition",
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: Category.collection.name,
        localField: "competition.category",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "category",
      },
    },
    {
      $unwind: {
        path: "$category",
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: Competitor.collection.name,
        localField: "competitor",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "competitor",
      },
    },
    {
      $unwind: {
        path: "$competitor",
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: Horse.collection.name,
        localField: "horse",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "horse",
      },
    },
    {
      $unwind: {
        path: "$horse",
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
      },
    },
    {
      $match: {
        "event.typeGroup": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id),
        GroupPosition: {
          $exists: true,
          $ne: null,
        },
        GroupScore: {
          $exists: true,
          $ne: null,
        },
      },
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: {
          competitionName: "$category.name",
          competitorId: "$competitor._id",
          horseName: "$horse._id",
        },
        competitor: { $first: "$competitor.name" },
        horse: { $first: "$horse.name" },
        TotalScore: { $sum: "$GroupScore" },
      },
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: {
          competitionName: "$_id.competitionName",
        },
        takeoffs: {
          $push: {
            competitor: "$competitor",
            horse: "$horse",
            TotalScore: "$TotalScore",
          },
        },
      },
    },
  ]);
```